# Python Pandas: combine 2 dataframes, one frame's column as the final result's index

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame df1:

```
+--------+------+--------+
| userId | isbn | rating |
+--------+------+--------+
|      1 | 0001 |      3 |
|      2 | 0002 |      4 |
|      2 | 0003 |      5 |
+--------+------+--------+
```

DataFrame df2:

```
+------+-------+
| isbn | title |
+------+-------+
| 0001 | aaa   |
| 0002 | bbb   |
| 0003 | ccc   |
+------+-------+
```

Can I merge them into:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |  1  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| aaa | 3   | NAN |
| bbb | NAN | 4   |
| ccc | NAN | 5   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

where the column is the **userId**, index is the **title**. **isbn** is dropped after the merge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) these frames, you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: merged = df.merge(df2)

In [12]: merged
Out[12]:
   userId  isbn  rating title
0       1     1       3   aaa
1       2     2       4   bbb
2       2     3       5   ccc

In [13]: merged.pivot_table('rating', 'title', 'userId')
Out[13]:
userId   1   2
title
aaa      3 NaN
bbb    NaN   4
ccc    NaN   5
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But dose this pivot_table method perform good when the DataFrame is very large? I have a 1 million rows table and 5 minutes later it is still running...

Comment: @EricZhang It could be that you're making an DataFrame which is sparse, so there is a lot of wasted space (NaN are put in memory). It should run "fast"... Maybe it's just too big to fit in memory? :S My guess is you can achieve your final goal using a groupby (may be worth asking another question about what your final aim is - what you are hoping to achieve with this) ?

Comment: The data is sparse but I do need them. I am gonna try to apply on a small set of data first. Thanks a lot!